# How do I dynamically indicate that a record is being edited by another user without refreshing the client

Tags: reactjs, react-native, socket.io

While I understand how to prevent a user from updating a record that is already being edited by another user (or is outdated since the last page refresh) - I want to dynamically indicate that a record is being edited by another user; maybe gray out the record or disable an edit feature, etc.

I'm envisioning this similar to how Google Sheets indicates that another user is editing a cell, etc.

Thanks

Comment: use mutex or semaphore.

Comment: You can use sockets.